# Is there any way to log windows log messages using rsyslog?

Tags: command-line, rsyslog

**Is there any way to log windows log messages in linux using rsyslog?**

even if any other open source methods are available, then your suggestions would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it myself, but take a loot at this project:
http://code.google.com/p/eventlog-to-syslog/

Answer (score 0):

The `rsyslog` project provides [a Windows agent](http://www.rsyslog.com/windows-agent/windows-agent-download/).